# Select multi rows from one query row acording to rows date Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a query. I want to select multiple rows for every row in query like this:

```
select process, fromdate, todate from
(
select 'A' as process, to_date('03.04.2013','dd.mm.yyyy') as fromdate, to_date('06.04.2013','dd.mm.yyyy') as todate
UNION
select 'B' as process, to_date('06.04.2013','dd.mm.yyyy') as fromdate, to_date('10.04.2013','dd.mm.yyyy') as todate
)
```

This show up like this:

```
Process     Fromdate       Todate
-----------------------------------------
   A       03.04.2013     06.04.2013
   B       06.04.2013     10.04.2013
```

But i need a query result like this:

```
 Process       Date
-----------------------
   A        03.04.2013
   A        04.04.2013
   A        05.04.2013
   B        06.04.2013
   B        07.04.2013
   B        09.04.2013
```

How can i do that?

thaks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select process, from_date + n
from (
    select process, fromdate, todate from
    (
       select 'A' as process, to_date('03.04.2013','dd.mm.yyyy') as fromdate, to_date('06.04.2013','dd.mm.yyyy') as todate
       UNION
       select 'B' as process, to_date('06.04.2013','dd.mm.yyyy') as fromdate, to_date('10.04.2013','dd.mm.yyyy') as todate
    ) s
join 
    (select level -1 as n from dual connect by level < 100) a
on (s.from_date+n < s.todate)
```

Comment: That realy helped me. Thanks! :)